# Help with Create View

Tags: mysql

My View is:

```
CREATE VIEW `vista_global` AS SELECT TC.nombreCentro, TP.Profesores, TA.Alumnos
FROM tbl_centros TC
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT centro, COUNT( * ) Profesores
FROM tbl_profesores
GROUP BY centro
)TP ON TC.idCentro = TP.centro
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT centro, COUNT( * ) Alumnos
FROM tbl_alumnos
GROUP BY centro
)TA ON TC.idCentro = TA.centro
```

But this not run well. Do you can help me, please?

Comment: Do you have indexes on Profesores.centro and Alumnos.centro?  Which queries are you executing against the view that are slow?

Comment: Can You paste examples of queries You run against the view and output of EXPLAIN of each query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use subqueries:

```
CREATE VIEW `vista_global` AS
SELECT TC.nombreCentro,
       COUNT(TP.centro) Profesores,
       COUNT(TA.centro) Alumnos
FROM tbl_centros TC
LEFT JOIN tbl_profesores TP ON TC.idCentro = TP.centro 
LEFT JOIN tbl_alumnos TQ ON TC.idCentro = TA.centro
GROUP BY TC.nombreCentro
```